# Creating a table in mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a table inside a mysql stored procedure, but whenever I execute this procedure, I do not see the resulting table in my database. Can anyone tell me what's going on? The create table query works whenever I enter it in the cmd outside of a stored procedure.

```
 delimiter //
    drop procedure if exists gm //
    create procedure gm()
            begin

        create table errorMessages (
        error_id int not null auto_increment,
        message varchar(200) not null default '',
        primary key(error_id)
        );

        end //
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: Are you then running the stored procedure after creating it?

Comment: Do you receive any error on calling the procedure?  Does the user under which the procedure runs have permission to `CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you executing the stored procedure or just creating it?

Try

```
call gm();
```

It gives any error?

Comment: Question states: "*... but whenever I execute this procedure ...*".

Comment: The query looks ok, it should work if executes the stored procedure

Comment: I wondered the same thing but deleted my answer, could be interpreted as whenever I run this 'block of code'

Comment: Stupidly, I wasn't using call gm(). I was using source gm.sql, which wasn't executing the procedure at all. :(